# Date as a percentage for the progress bar

Tags: python, django

Good afternoon. Help me please.
There is a project on Django. The project has a code from bootstrap4 - progress-bar, I need this progress bar, but I can’t understand how to implement its performance, since it has data stored in percent, but I don’t have percent, but the project date, that is, there is a beginning Let's say the project is 01 02 2000 and the end of the project 01 02 2002 there are 730 days difference between them. Here's how I turn these 730 days into 100%, and the remainder - let's say 140 days, also turn into percent.

HTML Template

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Python Template

```
prjauth = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="")
    prjtitle = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="")
    prjdesc = models.TextField(verbose_name="")
    prjfiles = models.FileField(upload_to='files_project', verbose_name="")
    prjdatestart = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="")
    prjdateend = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
    prjproekts = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
    prjproekte = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
    prjdatesnabs = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
    prjdatesnabe = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
    prjdatelines = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
    prjdatelinee = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method to your model which can return the date progress:

```py
Class MyModel(models.Model):
    # fields

    def get_progress(self):
        return timezone.now().date - self.start_date / self.end_date - self.start_date
```

The method can be called in your template:

```html
aria-valuenow="{{ mymodel.get_progress }}"
```

Lastly, I would suggest removing the `prj` prefix on your model fields as it makes it hard to read - presumably your model is already called something like Project - it would therefore be easier to read `project.start_date` than `project.prjstart_date`.

Comment: Installed everything.
But there was an error 
```TypeError at /
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'
```
Removed all prj prefixes, set more readable prefixes. But when you output 
```aria-valuenow = "{{project.get.progress}}"```
 the value is simply removed with the quotes.

Comment: My bad, put brackets around the two subtractions like so `return (timezone.now().date - self.start_date) / (self.end_date - self.start_date)
`

Comment: One more error.
```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: Hmm try this: `return (date.today() - self.start_date) / (self.end_date - self.start_date) ` and `from datetime import date'

Comment: TypeError at /
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime' 
Again this error

i'm add FROM DATEIME IMPORT DATE
and replaced return (date.today() - self.start_date) / (self.end_date - self.start_date)

Comment: Just realised that my own models use DateField and not DateTimeField, `datetime.now()` should work

Comment: As I understand it, now I change all ``DateTimeField to DateTime``? or what to change? I apologize, I do not understand much about Django and Python.

Comment: ``File "C:\djangos\portal\rpc\models.py", line 29, in get_progress
    return (date.today() - self.date_start) / (self.date_end - self.date_start)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime' ``
Console error

Comment: Great, it works.
``<div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 0,3407764065708681%" aria-valuenow="0,3407764065708681" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>``
 But is it possible to somehow translate this number into an integer? so that there is no comma, and it is rounded to the nearest whole number!

Comment: Yep, you can do `round()` (you'll want to multiply by 100 first though)

Comment: In general, the set here works very strange.
Assume the date 08 05 2020 to 09 05 2020.
He’ll highlight such a value, but do not allow 97%
``<div class = "progress-bar bg-success" role = "progressbar" style = "width: 681%" aria-valuenow = "681" aria-valuemin = "0" aria-valuemax = "100"> < / div>``
If I start dividing this by 10 - 100 -1000, then the result of those who have just started projects also changes.
In fact, I need to do so that 08 05 2020 was 0 and 09 05 2020 was 100 days (their difference) and it was already considered as a percentage.

Comment: Looks like your percentage is coming out in a strange way - 681 is higher than the valuemax!

Comment: valuemax=100
valuemin=0

Comment: Which is correct, but your valuenow needs to sit somewhere in between - do you know which dates are involved to get the 681 and have you changed the calculation at all?

Comment: models.py
``def get_progress(self):
        return (timezone.now() - self.date_start) / (self.date_end - self.date_start) ``
project_list.html
``<div class="progress-bar bg-success"
                                              role="progressbar"
                                              style="width: {{ project.get_progress|floatformat:'0' }}%"
                                              aria-valuenow="{{ project.get_progress|floatformat:'0' }}"
                                              aria-valuemin="0"
                                              aria-valuemax="100">``

Comment: ,I can throw off the model.py file and the output page.

Comment: Sure, if you want to update your original question with that it might be useful - I've just replicated the function and it works for me